# How can I return from one scene to another on Cocos2D

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to play a "cut scene" with cocos2d. I use:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCCrossFadeTransition transitionWithDuration:0.2 scene:[s node]]];
```

to play the new scene.

However, i want to return to the previous screen when i'm done playing this cut scene.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `pushScene:` to switch to the new scene (instead of `replaceScene:`) and `popScene` to return to the previous one (so this works like a stack).

This will keep the old scene in memory, see also [cocos2d Best Practices](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:best_practices#director_flow_control).

Comment: @roloenusa: If it helped you, you should accept the answer by clicking on the green tick beside it.